# Substituir Checkbox por Imagem

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Olá, não sei se é bem isto o nome do que quero.
Como vocês podem ver neste site: http://eyosongive.us/lolk/
Ao clicar em uma imagem ela é selecionada, gostaria de um código similar ou um em que ao clicar na imagem o checkbox seria selecionado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais simples de fazer isso é somente com HTML, usando [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label):

```
<label for="imagem1">
    <img src="http://eyosongive.us/lolk/data/img/aatrox_1.jpg" alt="">
</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="imagem1" />
```

Dessa maneira quando clicares na imagem, que está dentro do `label`, o browser vai agir da mesma forma que tivesses clicado no input diretamente.

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfnssLLL/

Se quiseres marcar a imagem como no site que referes podes fazer isso com CSS e JavaScript.

CSS:

```
.selecionada {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]')[this.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selecionada');
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfnssLLL/1/

**Aliás:** se o checkbox for sibling do label, e estiver antes, basta mesmo só CSS, sem JavaScript:

```
:checked + label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yfnssLLL/2/

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito ^^

Comment: Ah, mas uma coisa, no caso como faço para manter o checkbox selecionado?
Por exemplo: Utilizo o action="$_SERVE['PHP_SELF'"] Quando o dado é enviado o checkbox é desmarcado, como faço para manter marcado?

Comment: @Oliver o que queres dizer com "Quando o dado é enviado o checkbox é desmarcado"?